# HTTP resources on iOS

Tags: ios

I have a very simple question:

> Am I no longer supposed to access any HTTP resources in iOS?

I understand that HTTP, especially in a non-browser app, can be problematic. But I'm lost in all the documentation about App Transport Security and don't see the forest because of all the trees. Is the idea that iOS restrictions will eventually make it completely impossible to access HTTP resources? In other words, will I have to reroute every HTTP resources that I want to access on an iOS device via my own HTTPS server (which then pulls the HTTP content from a third party site)?

Note: I'm not asking for ways to get around the restrictions. There are plenty of answers for that.

Comment: Not "completely impossible". If you want to access a http resource (whatever it does), you need to allow it (or add exception) with related `App Transport Security` keys.

Comment: But is the idea that these exceptions will eventually not be allowed anymore?

Comment: The idea is; attempting to connect using insecure HTTP is not allowed starting from **iOS 9.0** (or macOS 10.11) **by default**. But you can add [exceptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsexceptiondomains) to discard this restriction to access http resources.